# Reversing translation of (error) messages?

Tags: localization

A device presents me with an error message, and I want to google the problem.

The error message is displayed translated, making it harder than necessary to find others with the same issue and/or a solution.

Is there a way I can search the translation dataset and find the original string in english?

Comment: What android ROM are you referring to? What version? What error message? What device? *a lot of things missing from this question*... please elaborate and clarify? Thanks :)

Comment: You might be able to (temporarily) switch the system language in the settings, provike the error message, write it down, and switch back. While the system language is switched, all apps will use this (if not explicitly told otherwise).

Comment: @t0mm13b I deliberately tried to make the question as generic as I could, assuming that the android SDK provided a standardized way of handling translatable strings. Are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: by deliberately leaving things out and making it generic falls under the "broad-scope" which in some cases can be off-topic. Please leave as much information in it - we're not psychics... :)

Comment: One thing you could try is to google for the translation, which *might* turn up the translation XML file holding both, original string and translation. Worked for me a couple of times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around, it turns out that there is indeed a way to handle localization in the SDK that could help answer this question, but from the [Localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) documentation, I don't get the impression an end-user can easily find these files and read them.

Izzy's two suggestions from the comments are really the best available solutions here.

1. Switch the system language in the settings, provoke the error message, write it down, and switch back. While the system language is switched, all apps will use this if not explicitly told otherwise.
2. You could try is to google for the translation, which might turn up the translation XML file holding both, original string and translation.